# Why is the variable getting replaced with previous command in perl?

Tags: perl, csh

I'm trying to replace only the first occurrence of a pattern in a file using a perl one liner.

```
>touch tmp
>perl -p -i.bak -e '++$seen if( !$seen && s/alpha/beta/);' tmp
```

After this I press Enter. Below message appears on the screen.

```
perl -p -i.bak -e '++$seen if( tmpseen && s/alpha/beta/);' tmp
```

Note that `!$seen` got replaced with `tmpseen`.

Why is this happening?

Thanks.

Comment: This is due to csh. `!$` is expanding to the last argument of the previous command. I'm assuming that.

Comment: @kjprice indeed. that seems to be the case. what can I do now?

Comment: @user13107 I don't use csh, but I'm guessing `if( \!$seen` will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can escape any csh special characters with `\` :

```
 perl -p -i.bak -e '++$seen if( \!$seen && s/alpha/beta/);' tmp
```

Answer (score 4):

As kjprice mentioned !$ gets expanded by the shell. One possible solution is to use the operator 'not' instead of the operator !.

```
perl -p -i.bak -e '++$seen if( (not $seen) && s/alpha/beta/);' tmp
```

Parentheses are there because of the lower precedence of the operator 'not'